# How to display Tableviewcell as bubble in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview

I know there is libraries which can do it for me but i don't want to use any library and do it manually. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by bubbles? Show us what you have tried and the UI design of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Like in the above Picture  Dávid Pásztor

Comment: You can use some third party libraries to do it. For example, you can use https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController or this one https://github.com/QuickBlox/QMChatViewController-ios as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually easier than it seems, you just have to set up a `cornerRadius` for your cells main view and set `clipsToBounds` to true.
As for the left/right alignment, you can either use two different prototypes with fixed constraints or you can modify your `Autolayout constraints` programatically based on the cell.

For the rounding, see below code working with a basic `UITableViewCell` (you will most probably be using your own subclass, but the principle is the same):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5 //set this to whatever constant you need
    cell.backgroundView?.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How to set tableviewcell height according to label

Comment: Use Autolayout and set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.